# Awk-substitution pattern

Tags: awk

I have two sample files:

file1:

```
Bolek
jeden(wzór1)
Lolek
dwa(wzór2)
trzy(wzór3)
```

file2:

```
czerwony
zielony
niebieski
```

I tried the command:

```
awk '{while(getline a < "file2"); sub(/wzór1/, a); print }' file1
Bolek
jeden(niebieski)
Lolek
dwa(wzór2)
trzy(wzór3)
```

I want to replace `wzór1` of "file1" on the contents of "file2". 
I want to print:

```
Bolek
jeden(czerwony
zielony
niebieski)
Lolek
dwa(wzór2)
trzy(wzór3)
```

Comment: Using getline is almost always the wrong approach. see http://awk.info/?tip/getline

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way:

```
$ awk -v val="$(<file2)" '{sub(/wzór1/,val);}1' file1
Bolek
jeden(czerwony
zielony
niebieski)
Lolek
dwa(wzór2)
trzy(wzór3)
```

The content of file2 is read into a variable "`cont`". This variable is passed to `awk` and all the occurence of wzor1 is replaced with the variable content.

Comment: Just be aware that this approach will strip any blank lines from the end of file2 rather than reproducing the contents of file2 as-is. That might be desirable or it might not occur in your specific input file, but it's something that you should be aware of.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{r=r s $0; s=ORS; next} {sub(/wzór1/,r)} 1' file2 file1
```

Assuming you are on UNIX, here's the difference between the approaches in the 2 posted solutions so far, note the empty line at the end of "file2":

```
$ cat file2
czerwony
zielony
niebieski

$ awk 'NR==FNR{r=r s $0; s=ORS; next} {sub(/wzr1/,r)} 1' file2 file1
Bolek
jeden(czerwony
zielony
niebieski
)                   <--- note the empty line is reproduced
Lolek
dwa(wzr2)
trzy(wzr3)
$ awk -v val="$(<file2)" '{sub(/wzr1/,val);}1' file1
Bolek
jeden(czerwony
zielony
niebieski)          <--- note the empty line has been removed
Lolek
dwa(wzr2)
trzy(wzr3)
```

If you're not on UNIX then the shell solution would be N/A anyway I assume.

Comment: @steve but it works independent of the OS (which the OP hasn't told us about) and reproduces file2 exactly as written so it's more portable and robust than the posted shell solution.

Comment: Ahh I often forget to check for emptiness. Good catch. You're right, empty lines could be important, although it's impossible to tell given the question.

Comment: @steve chances are the OP is on UNIX and that removing trailing empty lines doesn't matter for his input, just worth mentioning. And for me doing it all in awk does come naturally but YMMV and nothing wrong with mixing in some shell to make it briefer if you're on UNIX anyway.